# FeignClient exception in Spring Boot Microservices status 302

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign

i have a problem with FeignClient. Right now, I have authentication & authorization via okta. I have 3 services(one is api-gateway, one is discovery service - Eureka and one is backend). In api-gateway I have declared backend client:

```
@FeignClient("backend-service")
public interface BackendClient {
    @GetMapping("/api/things")
    ResponseEntity<List<Thing>> getThings();
}
```

Here is my application.yaml part with feign declared

```
feign:
    client:
        config:
            default:
                connectTimeout: 160000000
                readTimeout: 160000000
hystrix:
    enabled: false
```

However, when request is send, I get only

```
feign.FeignException: status 302 reading BackendClient#getThings()
```

Do You have any idea does this happen and how to solve it?

Additions:
Both services are registered on Eureka, i can check that they exist and they are up and healthy.

Zuul routes are configured properly.

Comment: are you deploying your application in PCF? 

If so can you please look at this questions as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454753/feignexception-status-302-reading-myservicedummy-content

Comment: I have already checked that question. I am not deploying it there. Well, I have checked and made some changes, so right now I see 401 as unauthorized. It looks like that token from (@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser user) which I got via user.getIdToken().getTokenValue() is wrong. Should I try to find another one or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am hitting Feign client 302 too, did you resolve this issue?